# Should I approve edits removing seemingly relevant tags?

Tags: discussion, edits

Since I recently reached the 2k mark, I've gained the ability to approve or reject edits. I've noticed a few suggested edits now that are simply getting rid of tags, and the comment will say something like "Removed extra tags."

As far as I can tell, the tags are relevant to the question. Is this something that I should be approving? I don't see the problem of having a a few tags.

Comment: @Rene I did see that, but I was more wondering if too many tags are an issue if they are relevant to the question.

Comment: If the removed tags are "seemingly relevant" then that edit is making "no improvement whatsoever" and should be rejected.

Comment: @ryanyuyu that has been my train of thought, but I have seen a few edits similar to this get approved by other users.

Comment: Yeah those are controversial approvals.  I personally think suggested edit reviewers, on average, are too lenient and should reject more stuff.

Comment: Examples, please! Sometimes the tags are relevant; sometimes they aren't.

Answer (score 4):

If the tag is relevant, as in the excerpt matches the topic of the question, I don't see a reason to remove tags, so I would reject such suggested-edits.

I wouldn't use the votes of other reviewers as an indication as the suggested edit queue is known for its robo-reviewing which normally means clicking *Looks good*. There is an [edit monitor](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) running in the SO Tavern to report reviews that are approved while it had rejection votes.

Comment: Purely from curiosity, I was just perusing some of the edits that the monitor plopped [there](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks), and some are just meh, but some are really egregiously bad.  Now I'm wondering, is anything done about them once they're dumped there?

Comment: @Ajean: If they are bad, most likely someone will go and correct things.